# Trying to Get child node(Switch ) from Parent(LinearLayout) via AndroidFindby(resourceid), Appium

Tags: xpath, appium, parent-child, resource-id

```
(class=android.widget.LinearLayout,resource-id=settings_language_selection_toggle,index=1 ) 

      (class=android.widget.RelativeLayout,index=0)

      (class=android.widget.LinearLayout,resource-id=widget_frame, index=1)

            (class=android.widget.Switch,resource-id=switchWidget, index=0)
```

/////////////
You can have a look at the hierarchical representation of the elements below

Hierarchy Image View:

[image]

***I have tried to reach the switch button by writing the below code on appium Android for java, but it did not work

```java
@AndroidFindBy(xpath ="new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.idscan.mjcs.sample:id/settings_language_selection_toggle\").instance(1).getChildById(new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.Switch\")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using UiSelector syntax in XPath strategy. That is why it isn't working. Try this one:

```java
@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "resourceId(\"settings_language_selection_toggle\").childSelector(className(\"android.widget.Switch\"))")
```

As you can see here, some boilerplate can be omitted, e.g. `new UiSelector().resourceId(...)` can be simplified to `resourceId(...)`. One more thing: once you found the root element (LinearLayout with the given resourceId), you can find any child element in the hierarchy using `.childSelector()` method, nesting doesn't matter.

Comment: Privet Sir, Thank you very much. I have tried what you have written and It worked successfully

Comment: I am glad to help